# trim between two particular character in php

Tags: php, trim, space

I want to trim space between two special character in a string in PHP. I mentioned my string given below.

```
$string= "{102)The quick brown fox{201}   {501}jumbs over the{102}lazydog{201} {501}
```

I need to remove the space between these }  { character in this string.

the result should be like this:

```
$string= "{102)The quick brown fox{201}{501}jumbs over the{102}lazydog{201}{501}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of spaces between the characters is variable, you probably need to use a regex like the following

```
$str = preg_replace('/}\s+{/', '}{', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always a single space, why not just do:

```
$str = str_replace('} {', '}{', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (and probably most efficient way in your case) is to use the built-in [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function to do the replacing for you.

For example:

```
$output=str_replace('} {','}{',$string);
```